# Transparent artboard backgrounds in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, background, artboard

I love the Photoshop artboard feature, however I'm used to seeing the transparent background grid. Is there any way to show this in my artboards in Photoshop?

And yes, I know it will still save with a transparent background, but I like having the grid that way if I were to use a white background for something I would be able to distinguish the white object from transparent.

Picture for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Photoshop CC 2015.5 you can now have artboards with transparent backgrounds.

Either create a new Artboard and select `Transparent` under the `Background Contents` menu or, if you have an existing artboard, simply select it in the layers panel, open up the properties windows and change the background with the `Artboard background color` dropdown. (Note that you can change the background of each individual artboard separately or change them all at once by selecting the artboards in the layer panel.)

[image]
Screenshot from [5 Hidden Gems in Photoshop CC](https://youtu.be/tvGKut9yG-M?t=7)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks @Johannes !

Comment: This feature is missing in CC 2015.1.1

Comment: That's correct, @Green. As I said in my answer it's available starting 2015.5.

Comment: And still relevant in 2023! Thank you so much! 

Answer (score 3):

As much as I understood, answer of your question would be like this..

1) Take a certain size of file(file A)

2) Now you will have a screen with transparent background. without doing anything else further, first of all take a screen shot of such screen.

[image]

3) And past it new file.(file B), keep only transparent grid image and delete the surrounding stuff and save transparent grid image as png or jpg.

4) Now come back from file:B to file: A and give background colour.

5) Bring transparent grid image in file A, set image as you want to see(for   example: 300x300).

6) take another layer on transparent grid image and draw square white shape size of 300 x 300..so that you would be able to distinguish the white object from transparent.

7) Now you will have a file like this.
[image]

That's it... Good luck !

Comment: It seems this is the only solution. Would still be nice to have a built in way of doing it though.

Comment: @JoshRiser there is a way of doing this with the inbuild options. See johannes' answer below

Comment: Problem with this though is you don't achieve actual transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Select the background layer.
Double click so it is no longer locked, it will rename as layer 0.
select all within your canvas (cmd + a) and delete.

Comment: That will not work on Artboards, which is what the questions is about.

Answer (score 0):

While you create a new file (menu > NEW). Select "Background Contents" drop to Transparent... Now you will get a transparent artboard.

Comment: Your answer is referring to just regular files, however in Photoshop CC there are now artboards as well. They do not have a `Background Contents` option.

Comment: As of Photoshop CC 2015.5 this will now work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screen shot and then open it as image. It's simple and you don't have to worry about [white background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbSWDx5fcms) .

Answer (score 0):

....Or you could create the board from the outset:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set artboard background

In the Properties panel (Window > Properties) for the artboard, set the desired value for Artboard Background Color field. You can also set the artboard background to transparent.

Answer (score -2):

Window -> Properties. 
Make sure Artboard is selected. 
See properties panel (that should be visible now) -> In the Artboard background color dropdown select: **Transparent** (white is selected by default).

You can check a quick (12sec) video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9sgajjbrZk

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the input, made the requested updates. An upvote would be appreciated :D

Comment: retracted the downvote, although your answer doesn't add anything new to Johannes' answer.

Comment: Thanks :) just wanted to add the video.. And I don't have enough reputation rank to comment on an answer... Hence my own post "_,

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote / downvote / comment

Comment: Alright man sheesh

Comment: No need to be rude, I'm just explaining you the rules we follow around here, and how you can better contribute to the community

Comment: Hi man wasn't trying to be rude, sorry. I just posted what I thought would be a helpful addition to this answer. It is frustrating to build up rep, especially with a busy schedule. And your comments just didn't help my good intentions, as misguided as they where. Will try going the more legit rout, even though I am not really sure what that is at the moment.

Comment: No problem. as cool as building rep might sound, don't worry much about it. Focus on giving good answers and asking good questions (whenever you have one - otherwise just upvote questions you like). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!